# emulator showing error "Nand :bad args ..."

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am just a beginner in this field ..so plss explain me step by step.I created a virtual device on platform 2.3.3.But whenever i launch it,it pops up with a window showing

starting emulator for "name".
(loading).
Starting emulator for AVD 'AMD-A10-480x800mdpi'.
NAND: bad arg:  Serious and Playful Science of Android Apps\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk/platforms\android-10\images/system.img.

and nothing happens.

(i m having an AMD processor,so  i m having ARM EABIv7a instead of intel86x)

what should i do...plss help me.

Comment: It seems your AVD is misconfigured. ARE YOU SURE of 480*800 mdpi? normally, it's hdpi.

Answer (score 0):

Re-install emulator and make sure that there are no folders that contain commas in the name in the path to system.img.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the path.  Change the folder 'Serious and Playful Science of Android Apps'  name to a single word. Ex: Android.. Then do other steps.. It worked for me.